# fire onchange/alternative event with window.opener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched almost all the pages but didn't find any proper solution.
I have opened a window with window.open and run a query which forms a table of values. when i select a row its values are populated to the parent window. 
In parent window i need to perform an action when the values are populated.

```
window.opener.document.formname.fieldname.value = tr.children("input.tdid").val();//in child window

//in parent window //jquery is included and formid="formname"
$("#formname input[name=fieldname]").on("change",function(){
//do some stuff
});
```

I know change event is fired only when we perform any action on input... and here i also cannot use trigger on value set. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my problem with a small hack.As of now it is working fine but i am not sure whether it will results errors in future.

```
window.opener.document.formname.fieldname.value =//something 
window.opener.document.formname.fieldname.focus(); 
window.close();
```

And i am catching the focus event in my parent window.

```
$("formname input[name=fieldname]").on("focus",function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you are updating the fields of the opener (parent window) yourself, using jQuery/Javascript, you can invoke the `window.opener.action()` [or whatever you may want to name it.] function immediately after the field change yourself. Thus eliminating the need for an `onchange` event trigger.

Comment: My child window does not have full access to perform all actions on parent window so i cannot right the function there itself. But your answer helped me in finding my solution... Thanks for the reply and answer.